# amazon elastic beanstalk eb local run with problems in my machine

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

ERROR: You can use "eb local" only with reconfigured, generic and multi container Docker platforms.

I want to create a multi container docker container web server on Amazon. 
I have already created an reconfigured - generic - multi container environment on amazon. 
I am trying to run this command to test my `Dockerrun.aws.json` file before deploy it but it is not working

I have already tested with amazon's example dockerrun but it didn't work

Dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
"AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
"volumes": [
    {
        "name": "php-app",
        "host": {
            "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/php-app"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "nginx-proxy-conf",
        "host": {
            "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/proxy/conf.d"
        }
    }
],
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "name": "php-app",
        "image": "php:fpm",
        "essential": true,
        "memory": 128,
        "mountPoints": [
            {
                "sourceVolume": "php-app",
                "containerPath": "/var/www/html",
                "readOnly": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "nginx-proxy",
        "image": "nginx",
        "essential": true,
        "memory": 128,
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "hostPort": 80,
                "containerPort": 80
            }
        ],
        "links": [
            "php-app"
        ],
        "mountPoints": [
            {
                "sourceVolume": "php-app",
                "containerPath": "/var/www/html",
                "readOnly": true
            },
            {
                "sourceVolume": "awseb-logs-nginx-proxy",
                "containerPath": "/var/log/nginx"
            },
            {
                "sourceVolume": "nginx-proxy-conf",
                "containerPath": "/etc/nginx/conf.d",
                "readOnly": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a bug in EB CLI blocking use of `default_platform: Multi-container Docker 17.03.1-ce (Generic)` . You can find more here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/awsebcli/3.10.4
Update your EB CLI before go any further.

What's more, if you created AWS beanstalk application in AWS Console (with browser) and then kinda imported it with `eb init`, there's a small change in `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` causing `eb local run` to fail with message

```
ERROR: You can use "eb local" only with reconfigured, generic and multi container Docker platforms.
```

For instance, in my `config.yml` for imported application created with AWS Console, I've got

```
default_platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-1::platform/Multi-container Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.4
```

Just change it to be

```
default_platform: Multi-container Docker 17.03.1-ce (Generic)
```

and you're ready to go!

*Tip: If there's a reason you don't want to update your EB CLI then use*

```
default_platform: Multi-container Docker 1.11.2 (Generic)
```

Comment: It answered my question

Comment: If you could answer this question for me too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46165305/error-writing-dockerrun-aws-json-v2-file

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/docker.html#single-container-docker.test-local guide.

Here I have included the details I've used as a workaround for this in 2023: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-elastic-beanstalk-developer-guide/issues/149#issue-1634369387

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34079255)

Comment: Basically, the [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/docker.html) tell you to do `eb init -p docker <appname>`, but it should be something like `eb init -p "Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2" <appname>`.  The value `docker` is valid but outdated and leads to this error.