# Error writing dockerrun.aws.json v2 file

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx

I am using this file to deploy a multicontainer nginx php-fpm application in AWS.

I run eb local run and shows me this error.

**holdbusinessnginx_1  | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "php:9000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf:1
elasticbeanstalk_holdbusinessnginx_1 exited with code 1**

It probably is because nginx is running before php-fpm.

In docker-compose.yml file there is a directive called depends-on.

Is there a way to use it in dockerrun.aws.json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use directive of

```
  "links": [
    "php"
  ],
```

where `php` will be the name of other container you defined in the same `Dockerrun.aws.json` file. EB is kinda guessing the dependencies on the links, volumes etc. So with forcing `nginx` container to link to `php` you're saying to the EB that `php` should get up before `nignx`. In shortcut. :-)

Comment: Sorry to disturb you so much. But can you help with that too ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46532411/does-not-get-asset-symfony-eb-local-run

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to take so much for the response. It was really that. A misatention mine.